# No Signal Analyzer session in mat file

Tags: matlab

I have a csv file with different columns like gravity, accelration, rotation, attitude with x,y and z axis. I am trying to make use of Signal Analyzer app in matlab. I imported the csv file in matlab and then saved it as .mat file format again. Then i opened the signal analyzer app and tried opening the file in the analyzer but got an error saying

```
  The MAT-file does not contain a valid signal analyzer session
```

Here is the picture of my data [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sRJF.jpg). How can i set my data so that the signal analyzer starts reading it? Or is there something that i am misssing that i need to add using code in my csv file?

Comment: From the error it looks like you're trying to open a [signal analyzer session](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/using-signal-analyzer-app.html#bu7wpo7). What you actually want to do is load your signal into the MATLAB workspace then [select it using the signal analyzer app](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/using-signal-analyzer-app.html#bu6ke0n).

Comment: @jodag my main goal is to check for the noise in data. Signal analyzer provides many such built in tools so that we can easily analyze the data and also get our scripts generated. I am beginner and can you please tell me what do you meant by load your signal into MATLAB workspace? From what i understand you told me to load the csv file into matlab workspace using import data. But in my question i already said that i did loaded it into matlab and then saved again the file in .mat format.

Comment: The [MATLAB workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/create-and-edit-variables.html) consists of the variables you create and store in memory during a MATLAB session. In your case you could load your signal into the workspace using the command `load myfile.mat` in the MATLAB command window. Once it's in the workspace follow the instructions in the first link I provided to load the signal into the signal analyzer app. You may also need to change the format of the data to conform with the signal analyzer's supported input types.